# protoc-gen-dart: Plugin failed with status code 127

Tags: flutter, dart, protocol-buffers, dart-pub, proto

I am trying to use protobuf for dart but I am consistently getting following error

`--dart_out: protoc-gen-dart: Plugin failed with status code 127.`

I tried  `./pub global activate protoc_plugin` but that didn't help.

```
echo $PATH
/Users/nk/doc/gck/bin:/Users/nk/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/nk/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/nk/AndroidStudioProjects/el/flutter/bin:/Users/nk/.pub-cache/bin:/opt/apache-maven/bin
```

I am getting an error when I am running

```
 protoc --dart_out=./lib/gen ./protos/test-event.proto

/Users/nk/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart: line 8: dart: command not found
--dart_out: protoc-gen-dart: Plugin failed with status code 127.


protoc --version
libprotoc 3.13.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue was with dart not set in environment variable.

Adding dart's path to ./zshrc or .profile will solve the issue

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/nk/projects/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
```